# ios - how to call the ShareKit share from an action button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, sharekit

I am working from this example of setting up ShareKit: http://getsharekit.com/install/

and their example has this:

```
- (void)myButtonHandlerAction
{
    // Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://getsharekit.com"];
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"ShareKit is Awesome!"];

    // Get the ShareKit action sheet
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

    // Display the action sheet
    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

But the last line there gives me a syntax error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'navigationController'
```

Also, my function is defined like this because I was looking to invoke the Sharing library after the user pressed the share button:

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender
```

Would anyone know why I am getting this error and what would be the right way to invoke the share functionality in my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your entire code, it sounds like you don't have a UINavigationController, just a UIViewController. If that's the case, this should do the trick.

In you .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *NVC;
```

In your .m file

```
UIViewController *theViewController = [[TheViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TheViewController" bundle:nil];

self.NVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theViewController];

[[self window] setRootViewController:NVC];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```